# Which Non-parametric test to use with two Ordinal sets of data

Tags: regression, chi-squared-test, nonparametric, factor-analysis, ordinal-data

[image: Refer to this for question 4![1]]
[image: Refer to this for question 6]

I am trying to find which factors in Ques 6 are strongly related to company being rated high  as compared to others in  Ques 4 and similarly factors related to company being rated low.